# Visual Basic GDI+ Drawing Lines

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I am working on a simple VB interface that should allow the user to draw a line from the point the mouse is clicked down to whereever the mouse position is, then leave the line where the mouse button is released. I am new to VB GDI+ and could use some pointers or tips. I need it so that I can draw multiple lines on the same control panel and everytime I start a new line somehow make it that the Paint paint function does not have to loop through each line I already drew. Here is my Code:
    Public Class Form1

```
Dim down = False
Dim ptA As Point
Dim ptB As Point
Dim ptC As Point
Dim ptStart As New List(Of Point)    ' Starting point of each line
Dim ptEnd As New List(Of Point)      ' Ending Point of Each line

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
End Sub

Private Sub Win_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Win.MouseDown
    down = True
    ptA = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
End Sub

Private Sub Win_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Win.MouseMove
    If down = True Then
        ptB = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Win.Invalidate()    
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Win_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Win.MouseUp
    down = False
    ptC = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
    ptStart.Add(ptA)
    ptEnd.Add(ptC)
End Sub

Private Sub Win_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Win.Paint
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LawnGreen, ptA, ptB)
    For i = 0 To ptStart.Count - 1
        Win.CreateGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.LawnGreen, ptStart(i), ptEnd(i))
    Next
End Sub


End Class
```

In order to keep my existing lines, I stored the points in a list and each time I move the mouse while drawing, I call the Paint function and each time it is called, it loops through each point and draws a line between them. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

JD

**** Edit

```
Public Class Form1

Dim down = False
Dim ptA As Point
Dim ptB As Point
Dim ptC As Point
Dim ptStart As New List(Of Point)
Dim ptEnd As New List(Of Point)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
End Sub

Private Sub Win_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Win.MouseDown
    down = True
    ptA = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
End Sub

Private Sub Win_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Win.MouseMove
    If down = True Then
        ptB = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Win.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Win_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Win.MouseUp
    down = False
    ptC = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
    ptStart.Add(ptA)
    ptEnd.Add(ptC)

End Sub

Private Sub Win_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Win.Paint
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LawnGreen, ptA, ptB)
    For i = 0 To ptStart.Count - 1
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LawnGreen, ptStart(i), ptEnd(i))
    Next
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Don't use CreateGraphics.  Use the `e.Graphics` from the paint event you are in.

Comment: Thank you for informing me on that...but that does not help me with my question...any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't see a question mark in your post.  Is there an error?

Comment: Good point...and no there is not. I was just seeing if anybody knew another way to draw multiple lines without the Paint Event looping through all previous points. When I draw like 50 lines, everytime I move the mouse the screen flickers from the loop in the Paint function. Can I eliminate that flicker?

Comment: Get rid of CreateGraphics.  And call Win.Invalidate on the MouseUp.

Comment: This reduces flicker to almost nothing, but when I move the mouse I cannot see where my current line is. Should I use a PowerPack line shape to track that?

Comment: I can't see the changes you made from here.

Comment: Okay I added it under my Edit section. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Keep the `Win.Invalidate` for the MouseMove.

Comment: Okay, but now I am back to square one. The flicker is back and when I draw a ton of lines the loop runs everytime I move the mouse. What can I do so that I can keep all my existing lines without having to loop back through all my previous points?

Comment: I don't see the Invalidate on the MouseUp.  What is Win?  A panel?  If so, your panel needs to be DoubleBuffered, or just you a PictureBox instead.

Comment: I went and added it to my code and it didn't do anything better. Also Win is a panel but does not have a DoubleBuffered property with it.

Comment: Use a PictureBox instead.  It has double buffering on by default.  To use a Panel, you would have to create a new class inheriting from Panel and then you would have access to turn on the DoubleBuffered property.

Comment: I had no idea about that difference. It works perfect now. Thank you very much for your time and help!